# How to add an extra message in json using tastypie?

Tags: python, json, tastypie

This is my app/api.py

```
from app.models import Person
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
    class PersonResource(ModelResource):
        class Meta:
            queryset = Person.objects.all()
            resource_name='person
            # filtering = { "email" : ALL,"dob":ALL,"mobile":ALL}
            filtering = {
                'email': ALL,
                'mobile': ALL,
                'dob': ALL,
                }
```

It returns json successfully at: /api/person/?format=json@email=abcd@example.com

But i would like to add one more string in json output as "status" which will be True when filtering was success and False when there is no entry in database corresponding to given email.
How can i do that ?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to define your own `alter_list_data_to_serialize` method. The method is called right before returning response of the `get_list` request, which is the one in the question, and should return the final dictionary that will be serialized in the response.

Assuming you are not restructuring the objects list metadata (tastypie's paginator wraps the objects' list in a dictionary where `objects` points at the list, `total_count` hold counts of total objects, etc.), you could do the following:

```
def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
    data['status'] = data['total_count'] != 0
    return data
```

Otherwise, if you are using a custom paginator and want to include the `status` key in all of the resources, you could modify the `Paginator.page()` method to add the `status` key.